# Overflow: scroll causes container to hide overflow. Any way around this?

Tags: html, css, scroll

In my application I have a scroll container that holds multiple images in a grid. When an image is hovered it moves the image up, making it clear which one is hovered. This feature works perfectly fine in the middle rows, but at the very top row the images get clipped and it's an eye sore. I've searched as many variations of the question as I could, but can only find other issues relating to overflow: scroll and not this specific one. I have tried wrapping the images inside an inner container and setting the overflow on the inner container to visible but this did not work. I've also tried setting the z-index for the images higher than the container but as expected, this also did not work.

I've recreated the issue on codepen to help demonstrate what I'm talking about.

https://codepen.io/machetetwins/pen/abdKrOx

````css
 body {
  background: rgb(44, 44, 44);
}

.outer {
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.no-scroll {
  border: 3px solid green;
  overflow-y: visible;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.outer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.outer img:hover {
  bottom: 2em;
}

```
````

```html
<div class="outer">
  <img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/funny-weird-wtf-stock-photos-18-5a39260c08f8a__700.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="outer no-scroll">
  <img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/funny-weird-wtf-stock-photos-18-5a39260c08f8a__700.jpg" />
</div>
```

The bottom image when hovered shows the desired behavior, but the top one inside the scroll container clips.

Comment: to be honest, the image moving up is an eyesore.  why not just use a small change in opacity to indicate the hovered image?

Comment: In the codepen example you're right it's pretty ugly.. But in my actual app I think it looks nice & adds interactivity. I've asked this a few places with no answer so I'm thinking I might have to do something like you suggested instead. Appreciate you